# Android Drawing Line with 2 points

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Currently I'm developing an app, where line will be drawn from one point to another with button click on a bitmap. 
Here's my code in MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LineView lineview;
    Button button;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //lineview = (LineView)findViewById (R.id.lineView1);
   button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture); 
   //lineview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

          // lineview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
   });


 }
}
```

LineView.java - class that draws line

```
public class LineView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  }

public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defstyle) {
super(context, attrs, defstyle );
  }


public LineView(Context context) {
super(context);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
}

}
```

Right now it draws the line from the start using defined coordinates. I want line to be drawn using coordinates from 2 points that get declared in main activity. And that function should work after onClick. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `app.draw.line.LineView` use an `ImageView`, and then use `ImageView.setBitmap(bitmap)` where `bitmap` is the bitmap where you drew the line.

Comment: I tied to draw line inside of bitmap, but only got black screen. Plus now I focused on solving my problem with the help of 2nd answer, but with a little progress

Comment: Use [Canvas.drawColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawColor%28int%29) to fill the entire bitmap with a background color of your choice. Also try to give a size to either the `Bitmap`, or `ImageView`.

Comment: My bitmap was an image. And I tried to draw a line on it. So size and color were declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use customview by extending the view class to achieve this:
Let's call your custom class say LineView. So this is what Line should look like.

LineView.java

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.view.View;

    public class LineView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

  public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defstyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defstyle );
      }


    public LineView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
}

}
```

Now, you'll have to instantiate this in your mainactivity. You can do that using java code or xml. Using java code it will look like this:

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.graphics.Color;
   import android.os.Bundle;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     LineView lineview;
     Button button;

     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lineview = (LineView)findViewById (R.id.lineView1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    lineview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            lineview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: This code draws a line, but it doesn't do it in my layout. I mean, I want a line drawn when I click a button, but the button still should be visible and active. This code, though, sets different view.

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Don't forget to add a lineview object to your xml from the palette under 'Custom and Library Views'. let me know if it works.

Comment: I have updated the question. Code gives me an error.

Comment: It's the same as yours. Maybe I should somehow edit my manifest?

Comment: And in activity_main.xml I get one sentece, you can see it in updated question. Why is it not working?

Comment: checkout my edited response for the LineView Class...I've added those constructors...

Comment: Yes it works like charm, thanks. Question: How can I draw a line with coordinates that can change. I mean in the code we have unchangable ints. If I have 2 points that get declared with button click and I want line to be drawn with this click using coordinates of points in MainActivity, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom view class that extends `View`. Within that class you will override the `onDraw` method which is passed a canvas. create a `Paint` object and use it with the `drawLine` function above.

I would suggest looking up Finger Paint app tutorials. There are at least a few online, and they are a good introduction to custom views and overriding the `onDraw` method.

Comment: I see. I want to clear out few things: I use onDraw in MainActivity? And do you know any specific tutorial. I mean, I'm not creating painting app. I just want to draw a line from A to B.

Comment: You dont call onDraw yourself. You override the onDraw method of the View class. I cannot suggest a specific tutorial (it is off topic for SO), but if you google for a finger paint app it will have plenty to choose from. You may not be making a finger paint app yourself, but the fundamentals about custom views will be coverd in the tutorial which is what you will need to draw your line